# How to get weekdays in drop down in cakephp, with a default day selected?

Tags: cakephp

I want  the weekdays to be displayed in a drop down in cakephp, with a default
day selected.
My code is as follows
echo $form->input('Weekday', array('options' => array
('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday',
'Sunday')));
When I do like this it stores 0 value in database instead of day name.
Also I want to set a default selected weekday .
Please help!!!

Thanking you..........

Answer (score 1):

The `options` array works like `array('key' => 'value')`. The array **key** is what will be send the the sever, the **value** is what will be displayed in the dropdown. Since `array('Monday', 'Tuesday', ...)` is equivalent to `array(0 => 'Monday', 1 => 'Tuesday', ...)`, the value you receive on the server is `0`. Make your array look like `array('mon' => 'Monday', 'tue' => 'Tuesday', ...)` to get what you want.

To select a default option use the [`default` parameter](http://book.cakephp.org/view/755/options-default).

Answer (score 0):

you can try put an empty default by just enter like

input('field', array('options' => array(1,2,3,4,5), 'empty' =>'--choose--')); -->

u save in 0 value it might be your field is enter wrong or double check ur careless mistake. it can be properly work well in this code.

here is the link u can refer to

http://book.cakephp.org/view/201/options-empty

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using something like jQuery UI, or some other JS plugin for example and their DatePicker. It is really useful, in their web page there are a lot of examples so you can do it really fast and easy. I did it so time ago and I was really pleased from the result :)

Check this link : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/